# How to convert square overlay to circle to get selfie in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[flutter camera overlay](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_camera_overlay/example)

This plugin is used to add common camera overlay components such as ID Card, Credit Card, Texts, prompts or custom components. So it is by default in rectangle/square overlay. I want it in circle overlay to take selfie pictures. So user can set their face within that focus area and click pictures accordingly. So, How do I do it in circle shape. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the widget in a

```
ClipRRect(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(),
),
```

Or

```
Container(
  width: ,
  height: ,
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(shape:BoxShape.circle),
),
```